# How do I use common login for my selenium java project wise

Tags: selenium-ide, selenium-java

My web application is login based -
So every time I need to login to the tool and before I do operation in the tool.

I create a method for login operation, and when I am trying to call that login method login operation in another test script login operation is happened successfully.
But I can't run my current call class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.